# Trying to merge values for duplicate keys in Nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I merged 2 lists and created new list which is having both lists data but im struck at cleaning my nested list.I need to remove duplicates keys and merge values for that duplicate key

```
list1 = [('ID1', 'Name'), ('ID2, 'Name'), ('ID2', 'team')]

expected output should be:
[('ID1', 'Name'), ('ID2, 'Name,team')]
```

Comment: you missed a quote after id2 in list1

Comment: would a dictionary output be better than a list of tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the data as a dictionary which may be a bit easier to work with:

```py
list1 = [('ID1', 'Name'), ('ID2', 'Name'), ('ID2', 'team')]

# create a dict with empty lists as keys
pivot = {i[0]: [] for i in list1}
for i in list1:
    # set the value of the first item key to the second item
    pivot[i[0]].append(i[1])

# converted to list of tuples, could be faster without doing the conversion
pivot_tuples = [(k, v) for k, v in pivot.items()]

print(f'dict: {pivot}')
print(f'tupl: {pivot_tuples}')
```

Output:

```py
dict: {'ID1': ['Name'], 'ID2': ['Name', 'team']}
tupl: [('ID1', ['Name']), ('ID2', ['Name', 'team'])]
```

Comment: Thank you :) and yes dictionary looks bit easier to work with

Comment: From where you are picking list_of_lists??

Comment: @vinay sorry, it should be `list1` instead of `list_of_lists`, testing error. I edited the answer to refelct.